# mysql foreign key references same table field

Tags: mysql, database, foreign-keys

I have this table

```
   CREATE TABLE `product_category` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `category_id` (`category_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `category_id` FOREIGN KEY (`category_id`) REFERENCES `product_category` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

What I'm trying to get is to delete on cascade every record which category_id fields equals to id field, but I cant insert any record, it gives me an error

```
cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails('database/product_category', CONSTRAINT 'category_id FOREIGN KEY('category_id') REFERENCES product_category('id') ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your foreigh key value must point to existing `product_category (id)`, but there are no allowable rows in table. So make

```
category_id int(11) NULL,
```

instead your definition and insert first row like

```
INSERT INTO product_category SET name='test1';
```

Comment: setting category_id to NULL is working, but the fact is that I want that field to have 0 as default value, is that possible @Yuriy Novikov?

Comment: 0 value is impossible, because foreigh key assume either correct pointer to existing id or NULL. Row with id=0 is not exists, so it causes an error.